# how to split input in a Keras model

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, keras-2

I'm trying to do something that's pretty simple in `keras` with no success. I have an input `X` with size `(?, 1452, 1)`. All I want to do is split this input to a vector of 1450 and a vector of 2 and deal with them seperately in the network. I tried:

```
X1 = X[:, 1450:1452, :]

X2 = X[:, 0:1450, :]
```

and then do whatever I want. It compiles fine until it gets to the line where I create the model. I get an error saying that my Tensor object doesn't have any attribute called `_keras_history` even though it does. So i'm guessing `keras` converts X1 and X2 to a regular tensor. so, I tried using `Lambda layers` in the following way:

```
X1 = Lambda(lambda x: X[:, 0:1450, :], output_shape=(1450, 1))(X)
```

after using this, the network compiled and trained completely fine, and the only problem was saving the model to `json/yaml`. It gave me an error in the `copy.deepcopy` part saying:

> TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects. after researching online

I found out there's a problem in saving `Lambda layers` to `json` for some reason.

**Question:** Do you know of any way to split the input in a normal way that would allow me to save the model later? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more code with the place where an error occurs in the first step. And show stacktrace of an error if there is more information.

Comment: Can you use tf.slice?

Comment: Why not just have a model with two inputs?

Comment: tf.slice is the same as X[:, 1, :]... I wasn't aware there's an option to have a model with two inputs. I'll try. thanks!

Comment: After reading on feeding multiple inputs to my model and adjusting the code it seems to work. Thank you very much! had no idea the solution was so easy